# Retrieving an element

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

I'm beginner of **XML**. I'm using **libxml**. I created an **XML** file like this:

```
<example>

    <Path Name="one">Properties/one</Path>
    <Path Name="two">Properties/two</Path>
    <Path Name="three">Properties/three</Path>
    <Path Name="four">Properties/four</Path>

</example>
```

My question is how can i get for example ***Properties/one*** for ***one*** which is the path's name. ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the issue fetching the text or getting a substring from the text?

Comment: The issue is fetching the text

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your C++ code showing what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty you can do it like this:

```
std::string strRetVal;
xmlDocPtr pXMLDoc = xmlParseFile("filename.xml");  // read the xml file
xmlNodePtr rootNode = xmlDocGetRootElement(pXMLDoc); // get the root node (<example>)
xmlNodePtr pNode = rootNode->children;
while (pNode)
{ // walk through all children nodes
    if (pNode->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
    {
        std::string strElemName((char *)pNode->name)); // find all <Path> elements
        if (strElemName == "Path")
        {
            xmlAttrPtr pAttr = m_pXMLNode->properties;
            while (pAttr)
            { // walk through all the attributes and find the required one
                if (pAttr->type == XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE)
                {
                   str::string strAttrName((char *)pAttr->name);
                   str::string strAttrVal((char *)pAttr->children->content);
                   if ((strAttrName == "Name") && (strAttrVal == "one")) break; // found
                }
               pAttr = pAttr->next;
            }
        }
    }
    pNode = pNode->next;
}
if (pNode) 
{ // pNode is the element with an attribute "Name" of value "one"
   strRetVal = (char*)xmlNodeGetContent(pNode); // get its content (/Properties/one)
}
```